# Working with trees and pointers in Fortran

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been working on a Fortran 95 program which tries to guess what you're thinking of. It takes a file with lines of the form `id label question yes no`:

```
9
1 . Is_it_a_living_thing? 2 7
2 . Can_it_walk? 3 6
3 . Does_it_meow? 4 5
4 a_cat . 0 0
5 David_Mitchell . 0 0
6 a_bacteria . 0 0
7 . Is_it_electrical? 8 9
8 a_toaster . 0 0
9 hair_gel . 0 0
```

The reason for the underscores is the C implementation of this program which I made, which happily works with Fortran's formatting when reading. The code is below:

```
module types
   implicit none

   type node
      character (len = 32) :: label
      character (len = 128) :: question
      type(node), pointer :: yes, no
   end type node
end module types

program pangolins
   use types
   implicit none

   !type(node), allocatable :: nodes(:)
   type(node), pointer :: head, current

   ! Program

   head => parseFile()
   nullify(current)

   call freeAll(head)

   stop
contains
   function parseFile() result(head)
      implicit none

      type(node), pointer :: nodes(:)
      type(node), pointer :: head
      integer :: i, n, thisN, thisYes, thisNo
      character (len = 32) :: thisLabel
      character (len = 128) :: thisQuestion

      open(10, file = './file1')

      read(10, *) n

      write(*, *) 'Nodes: ', n

      allocate(nodes(n))

      do i = 1, n
         read(10, *) thisN, thisLabel, thisQuestion, thisYes, thisNo

         write (*,'(a24,a64,i4,i4)') thisLabel, thisQuestion, thisYes, thisNo

         nodes(i)%label = thisLabel
         nodes(i)%question = thisQuestion

         if (thisYes .eq. 0) then
            nullify(nodes(i)%yes)
         else
            nodes(i)%yes => nodes(thisYes)
         end if

         if (thisNo .eq. 0) then
            nullify(nodes(i)%no)
         else
            nodes(i)%no => nodes(thisNo)
         end if
      end do

      head => nodes(1)
   end function parseFile

   recursive subroutine freeAll(head)
      implicit none

      type(node), pointer :: head

      if (associated(head%yes)) then
         call freeAll(head%yes)
      end if

      if (associated(head%no)) then
         call freeAll(head%no)
      end if

      write (*,'(a24,a64)') head%label, head%question
      deallocate(head)
   end subroutine freeAll
end program pangolins
```

Currently the code just initializes the array and then attempts to cleanly free it again.

The issue is related to pointers to arrays and elements of the array. My function `parseFile` makes organising the tree easy by first parsing the nodes from the file into a pointer array and pointing the yes and no pointers by the index in the array, then returning the first element which is always the head of the tree. This is intuitive in C, which is where I'm coming from.

When I run this code, the second call to `deallocate()` in `freeAll()` causes a double free segfault.

I suspect I'm confusing this with the C version, which uses an array of pointers, so although I initialized the starting nodes as an array, I could free each pointer one at a time using in-order traversal as the tree may have grown larger since initialization, and then finally free the array. Here is the function I've been trying to port from C:

```
...
node_t* readFile(FILE* inFile)
{
    int noOfNodes;

    fscanf(inFile, "%d", &noOfNodes);

    node_t** nodes = (node_t**) malloc(sizeof(node_t*) * noOfNodes);

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfNodes; i++)
        nodes[i] = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    char* nodeLabel = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LABEL_SIZE);
    char* nodeQuestion = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_QUESTION_SIZE);
...
```

What am I missing? Backtrace below:

```
$ gfortran -pedantic -Wall -ggdb -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -o pangolins pangolins.f95 
pangolins.f95:65.6:

      head => nodes(1)
      1
Warning: Pointer at (1) in pointer assignment might outlive the pointer target
$ ./pangolins
 Nodes:            9
.                       Is_it_a_living_thing?                                              2   7
.                       Can_it_walk?                                                       3   6
.                       Does_it_meow?                                                      4   5
a_cat                   .                                                                  0   0
David_Mitchell          .                                                                  0   0
a_bacteria              .                                                                  0   0
.                       Is_it_electrical?                                                  8   9
a_toaster               .                                                                  0   0
hair_gel                .                                                                  0   0
a_cat                   .                                                               
*** Error in `./pangolins': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000858700 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3055875a4f]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x305587cd78]
./pangolins[0x400d7d]
./pangolins[0x400c70]
./pangolins[0x400c70]
./pangolins[0x400c70]
./pangolins[0x400ddf]
./pangolins[0x4018b6]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x3055821d65]
./pangolins[0x400b69]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 5636403                            /home/adam/utils/fortran/pangolins
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 08:03 5636403                            /home/adam/utils/fortran/pangolins
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 5636403                            /home/adam/utils/fortran/pangolins
00853000-00874000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3055400000-3055420000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 4459030                        /usr/lib64/ld-2.18.so
305561f000-3055620000 r--p 0001f000 08:03 4459030                        /usr/lib64/ld-2.18.so
3055620000-3055621000 rw-p 00020000 08:03 4459030                        /usr/lib64/ld-2.18.so
3055621000-3055622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3055800000-30559b4000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 4499543                        /usr/lib64/libc-2.18.so
30559b4000-3055bb3000 ---p 001b4000 08:03 4499543                        /usr/lib64/libc-2.18.so
3055bb3000-3055bb7000 r--p 001b3000 08:03 4499543                        /usr/lib64/libc-2.18.so
3055bb7000-3055bb9000 rw-p 001b7000 08:03 4499543                        /usr/lib64/libc-2.18.so
3055bb9000-3055bbe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3056800000-3056905000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 4460722                        /usr/lib64/libm-2.18.so
3056905000-3056b05000 ---p 00105000 08:03 4460722                        /usr/lib64/libm-2.18.so
3056b05000-3056b06000 r--p 00105000 08:03 4460722                        /usr/lib64/libm-2.18.so
3056b06000-3056b07000 rw-p 00106000 08:03 4460722                        /usr/lib64/libm-2.18.so
3057400000-3057415000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 4499572                        /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.3-20140911.so.1
3057415000-3057614000 ---p 00015000 08:03 4499572                        /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.3-20140911.so.1
3057614000-3057615000 r--p 00014000 08:03 4499572                        /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.3-20140911.so.1
3057615000-3057616000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 4499572                        /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.3-20140911.so.1
7fcb37dc5000-7fcb37dc9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcb37dc9000-7fcb37e04000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 4471039                    /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
7fcb37e04000-7fcb38003000 ---p 0003b000 08:03 4471039                    /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
7fcb38003000-7fcb38004000 r--p 0003a000 08:03 4471039                    /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
7fcb38004000-7fcb38005000 rw-p 0003b000 08:03 4471039                    /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
7fcb38005000-7fcb38006000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcb38006000-7fcb38125000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 4470960                    /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
7fcb38125000-7fcb38325000 ---p 0011f000 08:03 4470960                    /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
7fcb38325000-7fcb38326000 r--p 0011f000 08:03 4470960                    /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
7fcb38326000-7fcb38328000 rw-p 00120000 08:03 4470960                    /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
7fcb3834b000-7fcb3834d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffdefd3b000-7ffdefd5c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffdefd8e000-7ffdefd90000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffdefd90000-7ffdefd92000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FCB3801F497
#1  0x7FCB3801FADE
#2  0x30558358EF
#3  0x3055835877
#4  0x3055836F67
#5  0x3055875A53
#6  0x305587CD77
#7  0x400D7C in freeall at pangolins.f95:82 (discriminator 2)
#8  0x400C6F in freeall at pangolins.f95:74
#9  0x400C6F in freeall at pangolins.f95:74
#10  0x400C6F in freeall at pangolins.f95:74
#11  0x400DDE in pangolins at pangolins.f95:23
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The first deallocate works, however the subsequent one causes the issue. Note the second print of `a_cat` printed by the `write` just above the `deallocate()`.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that on the question. It's not the cause of the issue. I'll add a backtrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function result `head` inside the function `parseFile` is associated with an element of an array.  While the array that the element is part of is an allocated pointer target, the element itself is not.

The pointer that is the function result eventually ends up as the argument to the freeAll subroutine.  In `freeAll` you then deallocate the thing referenced by that pointer - that is you are deallocating something that is not an allocated thing.  This is a programming error.

If you want to deallocate the pointer target that the `nodes` array was associated with in the `parseFile` function, then you need to deallocate an array.  Perhaps the result of the function and the argument to the subroutine should be an array.

(In C, a pointer to the first element of an array can represent the entire array.  This is not the case in Fortran, aside from things like sequence association.)

(A style/safe programming issue - you should consider using a subroutine for `parseFile` instead of a function - functions are typically meant for use in expressions (which doesn't apply to this function, that does IO) and it is easy to make mistakes with functions that return pointer results, so they should only be used when required for other reasons.)